# How to add new word vectors to gensim.models.keyedvectors and calculate most_similar

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

According to [Gensim's page on WordEmbeddingKeyedVectors](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors), you can add a new key-value pair of new word vectors incrementally. However, after initializing WordEmbeddingKeyedVectors with pre-trained vectors and its tags, and adding new unseen model-inferred word vectors to it, the `most_similar` method could no longer be used.

```py
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors

test = WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors(vector_size=3)

test.add(entities=["1", "2"], weights=[np.random.randint(5, size=3), 
                                  np.random.randint(5, size=3)])

test.most_similar("2") #THIS WORKS

test.add(entities=['3'], weights=[np.random.randint(5, size=3)])

test.most_similar("3") #THIS FAILS
```

I expect the output to be a list of vector tags most similar to the input tag, but the output is:

> IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Comment: It would help readers if you format your code

Comment: thank you for your feedback! Just edited.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, I've figured out a solution to this.

In the `gensim.models.keyedvectors` file, under `class WordEmbeddingKeyedVectors`, we can change from

```
def init_sims(self, replace=False):
    """Precompute L2-normalized vectors."""
    if getattr(self, 'vectors_norm', None) is None or replace:
        logger.info("precomputing L2-norms of word weight vectors")
        self.vectors_norm = _l2_norm(self.vectors, replace=replace)
```

to

```
def init_sims(self, replace=False):
    """Precompute L2-normalized vectors."""
    if getattr(self, 'vectors_norm', None) is None or replace:
        logger.info("precomputing L2-norms of word weight vectors")
        self.vectors_norm = _l2_norm(self.vectors, replace=replace)
    elif (len(self.vectors_norm) == len(self.vectors)): #if all of the added vectors are pre-computed into L2-normalized vectors
        pass 
    else: #when there are vectors added but have not been pre-computed into L2-normalized vectors yet
        logger.info("adding L2-norm vectors for new documents")
        diff = len(self.vectors) - len(self.vectors_norm)
        self.vectors_norm = vstack((self.vectors_norm, _l2_norm(self.vectors[-diff:])))
```

Essentially what original function is doing is if there are no `self.vectors_norm`, it is calculated by L2-normalizing `self.vectors`. However, if there are any newly added vectors in `self.vectors` that have not been pre-computed into L2-normalized vectors, we should pre-compute them then add to the `self.vectors_norm`.

I'll post this as a comment to your bug-report @gojomo and add a pull request! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears the `add()` operation isn't clearing the cache of normalized-to-unit-length vectors that's created & re-used by `most_similar()`-like operations.

Just before or after performing an `add()`, you can explicitly delete that cache with:

```
del test.vectors_norm
```

Then, your `test.most_similar('3')` should work without the `IndexError`.

(I've [added a bug-report for this problem](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2532) to the gensim project.)

Comment: Hey there, I've added a solution I've figured out as an answer -- while your answer might work, it will significantly increase time it takes to run the code due to the fact that all the L2-normalized precomputed vectors that are cached in self.vectors_norm are erased after each addition of a new vector into the keyedvectors. My method essentially pre-computes the additional new vectors into L2-normalized ones and simply adds it to self.vector_norm so you can use them for faster performance.